# Tensorflow: When do I need to run a tf.Session() when using tf.Keras layers or tf.Estimator API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to reconcile information from the TF "Graphs and Sessions" Guide and the TF "Keras" Guide and TF Estimators Guides. Now in the former it says that the a tf.Session gives the computation graph access to the physical hardware to execute the graph and train the model. Like the initial tutorials on learning TF require you to use a Session in order to run anything: variables guide, Tensors guide, etc. HOWEVER, in the TF Keras guide, the examples seem to run without any explicit call to the `tf.Session` or the usual `with tf.Session() as sess:` The Keras model is not using eager execution either. The same is true in for the Estimators API.

I have a couple of code samples. Some of them use the call to the session while others do not. I was hoping someone could clarify what are the rules for requirements for using `tf.Session` with Keras layers or Estimators. I mean it seems like you can set up things like `run_configs` for the keras estimator or standard TF.estimator and set the settings for multi-gpu, etc.

Here is an example from the TF Keras Guide for the Functional API. Note that no call is made to the session:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,))  # Returns a placeholder tensor

# A layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor.
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

# The compile step specifies the training configuration.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Trains for 5 epochs
model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=32, epochs=100)
```

Thanks for any info or clarifications.

Comment: Keras uses a global default tf session in its tensorflow backend. See e.g. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py you can set a tf session in Keras using K.set_session if you want to run tf tensors/placeholder through Keras layers. See e.g. https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call of `tf.Session()` is not necessary when using only Keras. This is called when tensorflow backend is used, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py). This is only called when tensorflow backend is used and not with `theano` or `CNTK`.

Regarding the use of the Tensorflow interface with `tf.Session()` calls, this is explained [here](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html), which simply uses the `tf.Session()` as bridge between Keras and *pure-TensorFlow* tensors and/or functions.

You can see an example of using `tf.Session()` with Keras, using `set_session()` backend function:

```
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

from keras import backend as K

sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: Thanks @jgorosdev that makes sense. So there is a Session in the background. I just was not clear on why the TF docs make such a big deal about Session but then fitting a model does not require that explicit call. Thanks for the link to the Keras tutorial for connecting Keras to TF tensors.

Comment: If ``tf.Session()`` is deprecated, Use ``tf.compat.v1.Session()`` instead